# Реализация поиска в стиле графов

Tags: golang

Хочу сделать реализацию поиска совпадений в стиле графов или ещё как-то.
Есть много 16 байтовых строк, чтобы не проверять простым for хочу искать последовательно вглубь графа.
Т.е. я это вижу приблизительно так, каждая нода содержит массив где ключ ссылается на другой массив.
Первый байт помещаем в первый слой и делаем ммылку на следущий слой, где второй байт становится ключём.
Грубо говоря это как многомерный массив где первый байт это первый уровень, и он ссылается на вложенный массив где лежат вторые байты и строк.
В принципе есть два больших набора байтовых массивов фиксированной длинны, т.е. каждый элемент массива имеет одинаковый размер.
Нужно искать совпадения, подскажите куда копать?

Comment: Ничего не понятно. Опишите проблему, покажите примеры, свои идеи

Comment: Нет примеров, идея в том чтобы был своего рода многомерный массив где первфй байт будет  иметь ссылку на другой массив, т.е. проверяем первый байт, если он есть то проверяем дальше в глубину, если его нет то дальше можно не искать

Comment: Покажите, что нужно искать, на примере

Comment: Есть два набора байтовых массивов фикированного размера, и нужно искать совпадения. Хочу избавиться от for потому что сликом много лишней работы.

Comment: Пример на строках?

Comment: Данные в виде байтовых массивов.

Comment: Это неважно , на строках легче показать что требуется, пока это невнятно `искать совпадения`

Comment: Что именно невнятно? Есть два набора по 100 миллионов массивов по 16 байт, нужно найти совпадения если они есть.

Comment: Совпадение - когда совпадают все 16 байт?

Comment: Да, когда полное совпадение

Comment: ОК. Теперь насчёт `два больших набора`..  Нужно искать общие элементы набора A и набора B? Тогда можно отcортировать наборы или сделать множества (set)

Comment: Да, нужно искать общие "строки", один набор неизменный и его отсортировать легко, второй набор каждый раз разный.

Comment: Тогда из первого набора построить set, при обновлении второго проверять  каждый массив на вхождение в set

Comment: Вроде бы в Go нету set

Comment: map есть.......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проще всего организовать set - [в golang - на основе `map`](https://golang-blog.blogspot.com/2020/04/set-implementation-in-golang.html) из данных первого набора, и потом проверять значения из второго набора на наличие в этом множестве.

Хотя элементы данных не такие уж длинные, но всё-таки каждый 16-байтный массив второго набора будет обрабатываться полностью для вычисления хэша.

Поэтому стоит проверить и вашу идею про проверку первого байта, потом второго и т.д.  Одна из лучших структур данных для этого - trie.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Несовпадающие байты в большинстве своём будут отсекаться на ранней стадии, поэтому проверки должны быть довольно быстрыми.  [Вот произвольно взятая ссылка](https://golangbyexample.com/trie-implementation-in-go/) на реализацию trie на golang (выглядит не очень серьезно, но как отправная точка - подойдёт)

Comment: У меня в принципе такая-же идея, просто я не правильно назвал это, виесто дерева я обозвал это графом, хотя граф это немножечко другое. К стати тут сделано как я и думал, значит вектор идеи у меня верный.

Comment: В принципе это и есть ответ, то что мне нужно называется "Trie data structure"

Comment: Отлично. Посмотрел разновидности - просто trie  для вашей задачи, видимо, лучший вариант.

Comment: Я когда думал как искать менее затратно именно это и придумал, просто не знал как оно называется, поэтому и спросил.